# How to find file location which has been queued for printing

Tags: c#, wmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the original full file path been printed by Spooler API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236762/how-to-get-the-original-full-file-path-been-printed-by-spooler-api)

```
try
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2","SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob");
}

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Document: {0}", queryObj["Document"]);
}
```

This gives the document name, I need the location of the file.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236762/how-to-get-the-original-full-file-path-been-printed-by-spooler-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the document is passed to the spooler, it will not have any reference to this information. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for info on what fields are stored in Win32_PrintJob

Comment: you could send additional information on the job in the parameters if it is you submitting the print job.

Comment: is there any solution ? any way i can find the file path......?

Comment: so i guess there is no solution you can not find the original file path of file being printing or waiting in queue.