# Send PrintQueue object from one computer to another?

Tags: java, c#, printing, network-programming

So I have the following code to access the local printer and its current jobs in C#:

```
        PrintQueue pq = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
        PrintJobInfoCollection pjic = pq.GetPrintJobInfoCollection();
        foreach( var printjob in pjic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(printjob.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

What I want to do is send this PrintQueue object to another computer which is connected to a printer and add the jobs in this queue to jobs of that queue. So essentially, the idea is to print remotely over the networks. I have some network programming experience in Java but not enough to translate well into C#. So I was wondering if anyone can break it down for me. ( And I know there are tons of ways of configuring Windows/Mac OS to print from a remote printer but this application is a learning experience for me). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is working because I haven't tested it, but the idea is:

1. Set the PrintServer to the computer you want
2. Get the PrintQueue from the PrintServer
3. Iterate over jobs and add each job to that PrintQueue

---

Unfortunately, I cannot find any way to add print job directly, what I found is by [`PrintQueue.AddJob()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552914(v=vs.110).aspx) method that takes some arguments like job name, document path, etc.

```cs
// Step 1: Set the PrintServer to the computer you want
PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer("\\ANOTHER-COMPUTER-NAME");

// Step 2: Get the PrintQueue from the PrintServer
PrintQueue printQueue = printServer.GetPrintQueue("That Printer Name on Another Computer");

// Step 3: Iterate over jobs and add each job to that PrintQueue
foreach (var printjob in pjic)
{
    printQueue.AddJob(printjob.Name, "document path here", true, pq.DefaultPrintTicket.Clone());
}

// and then do, like passing the printQueue to the PrintDialog
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintQueue = printQueue;
```

For getting the document path, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236762/how-to-get-the-original-full-file-path-been-printed-by-spooler-api).